# How can I use php curl with multi threads?

Tags: php, multithreading, wordpress, curl

How can I make this script work with multi threads?
Already tried all tutorials but without success :(
And what is the maximum number threads I can use with curl php?

> ```
> <?php
> $imput  = file("$argv[1]");
> $output = $argv[2];
>
>
> foreach ($imput as $nr => $line) {
> $line = trim($line);
> print ("$nr - check :" . $line . "\r\n");
>
> $check = ia_continutul($line); 
>
> if (strpos($check,'wordpress') !== false) {
>
>   $SaveFile = fopen($output, "a");
>   fwrite($SaveFile, "$line\r\n");
>   fclose($SaveFile);
>   }
> }
> print "The END !\r\n";
>
> function ia_continutul($url) {  
>     $ch = curl_init();  
>     $timeout = 3;  
>     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
>     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  
>     curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
>   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);  
>     $data = curl_exec($ch);  
>     curl_close($ch);  
>     return $data;  
> }
> ?>
> ```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php

Comment: PHP is not multithreaded, and will most likely never will be without a fundamental re-engineering of the language.

Answer (score 4):

You can multithread in PHP ...

```
class Check extends Thread {
    public function __construct($url, $check){
        $this->url = trim($url);
        $this->check = $check;
    }
    public function run(){
        if (($data = file_get_contents($this->url))) {
            if (strpos($data, "wordpress") !== false) {
                return $this->url;
            }
        }
    }
}
$output = fopen("output.file", "w+");
$threads = array();
foreach( file("input.file") as $index => $line ){
    $threads[$index]=new Check($line, "wordpress");
    $threads[$index]->start();
}
foreach( $threads as $index => $thread ){
    if( ($url = $threads[$index]->join()) ){
    fprintf($output, "%s\n", $url);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

Answer (score -3):

You cannot multithread PHP.  It is a scripting language, so the script is ran in a certain order and if you have to wait for a curl to finish it will keep loading while that happens, it is like putting a Sleep(1) function in your code.

There are some basic things you can do to help speed up your code.  Do not do mysql request (I don't see any) inside a loop, instead build up a query then do it after the loop is over.  Look at restructuring your code so you can do the minimum number of curls so it goes fast.  Try to find a way to do the curl outside the loop.